# C# Event subscription to method

Tags: c#

I am attempting to subscribe two events to an object. But the object is not instantiated before I try to add the events. Is there a way I can subscribe these two events and instantiate afterwards? I already have the delegates, event, event args and event handler working.

**Sample Code:**

```
Ares a;

public B()
{
    a.up += new upEventHandler(doUp);
    a.down += new downEventHandler(doDown);
    a = new Ares();
}
```

Comment: Not unless the events are static. Events are like any other instance property: they can't exist without an instance.

Comment: Not really, there's no real way to store that information other than with the actual class object.

Comment: No you can't and more to the point why would you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am attempting to subscribe two events to an object. But the object is not instantiated before I try to add the events. Is there a way I can subscribe these two events and instantiate afterwards?

No, absolutely not. It's exactly like trying to set properties on an object before the object exists. Try to think about how *that* would work - and then realize that subscribed event handlers are part of the state of an object just like properties are.

Obviously you could store the event handlers somewhere else and subscribe them later on, but as stated, the answer is simply no. It doesn't make any sense at a conceptual level, or a practical one.

Comment: @user1221830 Taking a quick look at your sample code will show you exactly what's wrong with what you're trying to do.

`a.up += new upEventHandler(doUp);` what is `a.up`? if a isn't instantiated yet, then the program has no idea what `a.up` is, where it's located, what's stored there. if `a.up` was an int, you couldn't `a.up += 3;` if you haven't instantiated `a` yet could you?

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the advice. I ended up just changing them to static.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You must instantiate the object first.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you could do to what you're describing would be to make the events static.

```
class Ares {
    public static event upEventHandler up;
    public static event downEventHandler down;
    // ...
}
```

And then modify `B()` to be:

```
public B() {
    Ares.up += new upEventHandler(doUp);
    Ares.down += new downEventHandler(doDown);
    a = new Ares();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the events are fired in the constructor and you want to capture that.

Try refactoring the event firing code out of the constructor into a separate Initialize() method, so you would then have the following:

```
Ares a;

public B()
{
    a = new Ares();
    a.up += new upEventHandler(doUp);
    a.down += new downEventHandler(doDown);

    a.Initialize(); //do all init of the ares object here, not in constructor
}
```